# what is the best way to store and manage a refresh token in nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, saas

I would like to know the best way to manage and store refresh token. I am building an app  where i need to access a data API continuously even when the user is not logged in . So, should I use a database like MongoDB or redis and also what is the best way to manage refresh token and access tokens. For example how do i routinely refresh my access token.Are there any services to accomplish this task.
Any node modules?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oauth2 authentication to accomplish such thing like access tokon and refresh token and the best i personaly used is redis and it is stable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use passportJs for your token authentication process here is link [passportJs](http://passportjs.org/)